# How to include customized delegate methods in two different projects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I have created a delegate method in AppDelegate class. But in some classes its showing and in some classes its showing error that the delegate declaration can't be found and i've included appdelegate.h file also. After long search also its unclear, what is the root cause of the error. 
Can I get any hint on what is the issue and how to resolve it?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can read an objective-c beginners guide here:
[Objective-c for beginners](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html)

And another one which is really good to get started:

[BecomeAnXcoder](http://www.macxfire.com/documentation/BecomeAnXcoder.pdf)

Other than that, there is nothing I can do for you with such a vague question. Make sure that the .m file is in your project and that it is a member of your target. You know that when you create a new project it doesn't use the same appdelegate in that project from the beginning? You would have to replace it with the one in your other application

Comment: kinda hard with a vague question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to understand…

If you're getting your application delegate instance by calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`, the return value is an instance of `UIApplicationDelegate`, but it's not necessarily certain that it is *your* app delegate subclass. So that would explain why the method declarations aren't being noticed. In addition to importing your app delegate's .h file, you should cast the return value of the `delegate` message like

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```